# how to draw yuv buffer using opengl es in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

i am using android surface view to display images. i have a yuv frame buffer decoded from ffmpeg. how to convert yuv to rgb using opengl es and display it. is there any examples to convert yuv to rgb in android native code.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at paper below which gives basic c++ code and many improvements on this conversion which I also employed (excpt the SIMD part :).

http://lestourtereaux.free.fr/papers/data/yuvrgb.pdf

Moreover, depending on opengl version you are be using, you may put this conversion into even shaders.

Hope this helps... :)